# I would like to do this (1) in big size ? is it possible?

Tags: symbols

I would like to do this `(1)` in big size using latex (a one surrounded by a circle)

[image]

is it possible without including the picture ?

Comment: Do you need the digit `1` in the current font?

Comment: using `tikz`: `\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz \node[scale=4,shape=circle,draw]{1};

\end{document}`

Comment: it is working :) write it in an answer with more details on `tikz` (what is this package)

Comment: can you make it with  `\begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 0):

With `pstricks` and `pst-node`, you can circle about whatever you want with the  `circlenode` command`. Note that you have to give a name (first argument of the command) even if you don't want to use it. It can be compiled with`pdflatex`if you load pstricks xith the pdf option and compile with the`--shell-escape`(TeX Live) or`--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) switch :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdf, x11names]{pstricks}%pdf,  
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

Blahblahblah… \raisebox{-0.4\height}{ \circlenode[linewidth=2.5pt, linecolor = PaleVioletRed3]%
{A}{\color{PaleVioletRed3}\Huge\bfseries \sffamily 12a}}
```

Blahblahblah

```
\end{document}
```

[image]